# What's a stubble?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

https://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=stubble&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y&typeofrhyme=def

> material consisting of **seed coverings** and **small pieces of stem** or
>   **leaves** that have been separated from the seeds

I have no idea what a seed coverings look like, and what leaves separated from the seeds (what seeds) look like. Can someone post pictures of what a stubble can look like. It seems it can look like several different things. Google images gives a lot of pictures, but they don't really tell me what a stubble is. Looking at the pictures, I feel like it's the stem of harvested plants, but it doesn't really fit the definition, because it doesn't cover "seed coverings" part.

Comment: What is the source of the quotation? That does not match any meaning I know of the word "stubble". I would assume that the word being defined there was "chaff". (Both are uncountable, by the way).

Comment: Where'd you get this definition? It's not a word I've ever heard used in that context.

Comment: It is not a stubble, just stubble. It is what is left after you cut a plant in the ground or when a beard is beginning to grow. If you don't know what a seed covering is, google an image for it.

Comment: Why are you using "RhymeZone" for definitions instead of a good dictionary that will give you multiple definitions, pronunciation, example sentence, etc.? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stubble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definition is incorrect.  This definition would match the word "chaff".

Wheat is a grass, and you eat the seeds, which grow at the top of the stem.  When you harvest wheat, you cut the stem below the seeds, leaving the bottom of the stem still in the ground. [These stems are called stubble.](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/crop+stubble)

Next you shake the seeds to separate the edible part of the seed from the covering and any leaves etc,  the remainder is called "chaff" a google search shows many [pictures of "chaff".](https://www.google.com/search?q=chaff&sxsrf=ALeKk021mqRim4QuB-RoBU974nfNMy_bHg:1589312806863&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFzajKi6_pAhVQShUIHYd-BC8Q_AUoAXoECBQQAw&biw=1366&bih=669)

Comment: What they meant was crop stubble I think: [pictures of stubble](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/crop+stubble)

Comment: Those searches seem rather prone to link rot. Perhaps also look at the articles about [crop residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_residue) and [chaff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaff) on Wikipedia, which both have pictures.

Comment: The purpose of include search links is to demonstrate (subtly?) to the questioner, or anybody else looking at this answer, that "images can often be found by a simple web search", ie we "teach a person to fish so they can feed themselves". The trouble with linking to "crop residue" and "chaff" is that neither term appears in the OP's question, so why would they go to those pages?